# IntelliJ IDEA console

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I would like to know if IntelliJ IDEA for Java has a tool like the Pycharm Python console in the picture, which can save the variable executed before, and then use this variable in the next execution.
Because I find it very convenient.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGoI3.jpg)

I'm not really familiar with IntelliJ IDEA so would like to know, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For Java, you can use *JShell Console* in *IntelliJ*. Here's [the documentation page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/jshell-console.html) for it.

Another *IntelliJ* feature that you may find helpful is the [Scratch files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scratches.html)